# field cross search in lucene

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search

Hi:
I have two documents:

```
title                       body
Lucene In Action            A high-performance, full-featured text search engine library.
Lucene Practice             Use lucene in your application
```

Now,I search "lucene performance" using

```
private String[] f = { "title", "body"};
private Occur[] should = { Occur.SHOULD, Occur.SHOULD};
Query q = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_29, "lucene performance", f, should,new IKAnalyzer());
```

Then I get two hits:
"Lucene In Action" and "Lucene Practice".

However I **do not** want the "Lucene practice" in the search result.

That's to say,I just want the documents who own all my search terms can be returned,the "lucene parctice" does not contain the term "performance",so it should not be returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene cannot match across fields. That is to say, for the query `"a b"`, it won't match `"a"` in `title` and `"b"` in `body`. For that you need to create another field, say, `all_text`, which has title and body both indexed.

Also, when you are searching for `"lucene performance"` I suppose you are looking for documents that have both the terms - `lucene` as well as `performance`. By default, the boolean operator is `OR`. You need to specify default operator as `AND` to match all the terms in the query. (Otherwise in this case, the query "lucene performance" will start returning matches that talk about database performance.)

Comment: For English Characters searching,you are right. And I am looking for some ways to solve the Chinese Characters serching. Thank you anyway.